# How can I know which AJAX requests are pending?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, selenium

I have a simple C# method that waits for all jQuery AJAX requests to be done before moving on with my Selenium WebDriver test.

What I'd like is to know exactly *which* requests were pending when I hit my maximum amount of waiting. Is there any way to do such a thing? I poked around the web and jQuery documentation but couldn't find anything.

```
    public void WaitForAjax(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        const int ajaxSleepInMilliseconds = 250;
        int counter = 0;
        const int maxSleeps = 40;
        while (counter < maxSleeps)
        {
            var javaScriptExecutor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            var ajaxIsComplete = javaScriptExecutor != null &&
                                 (bool) javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
            if (ajaxIsComplete)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(ajaxSleepInMilliseconds);
            counter += 1;
        }
        if (counter >= maxSleeps)
        {
            var currentAjaxCalls = ""; // ???
            throw new WebDriverException("Maximum number of WaitForAjax Thread.Sleeps were hit. Waited for AJAX " +
                "for: " + ((maxSleeps * ajaxSleepInMilliseconds) / 60) + " seconds; the calls in progress were: " +
                currentAjaxCalls);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built in way of knowing about outstanding ajax requests.

You can either

- change script to intercept requests and notify your code about completion (i.e. using [ajaxTransport](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport/) )
- capture HTTP traffic to know when all outstanding requests are complete.

Comment: re. Capture HTTP traffic - If I use browsermob, how do I ensure there are no outstanding requests?